# How to set text view on and off when a button is clicked?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am doing a simple task in my project: I want to switch on and off text view when a button is clicked. How to set text view on and off when a button is clicked?

Comment: texview.hidden = YES/NO, or textview.alpha = 0/1. the second option can be animated

Comment: What do you mean by ON/OFF textView its not a switch right? Do you want to hide/unhide or enable/disable or bring keyboard/hide keyboard the text view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then you use

```
-(IBAction)button_clicked:(UIButton *)button
{
  textView.text = @"Your text";
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0
                                        target:self
                                      selector:@selector(clearText)
                                      userInfo:nil
                                       repeats:NO];
}

after 60 secs clearText method will be called

-(void)clearText
{
   textView.text = @"";
   //or
   textView = nil ;
 }
```

hope this will solve your purpose..

Comment: i want to make these text visible only for one minute ! the times should start when i click the button

Comment: now use my answer .. hope this will help... don't forgot to up vote

Comment: this is not the correct way to show your acceptance of answer.There is a "right" button along with my answer. You need to hit that one & up vote it....

Answer (score 1):

Toggle the [`UIView hidden`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/hidden) property.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (button.isSelected){
    [ button setSelected: NO];
    [myTextView setHidden:YES];
    [myTextView resignFirstResponder];
}else{
    [ button setSelected: YES];
    [myTextView setHidden:NO];
    [myTextView becomeFirstResponder];    
}
```

Comment: By on/off if you mean editable/uneditable on button click and not the hide/unhide, you can use userInteraction property in the above answer instead of hidden property. Just replace [myTextView setHidden:YES]; with [myTextView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES] and similarly for button not selected case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you also want its keyboard to be opened. To do this you need to make it the firstResponder from the action method wired to your button.

```
-(IBAction)myButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    [myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```